# modprobe uio_pci_genericco is failing on Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am running below command to load the uio_pci_generic driver

```
modprobe uio_pci_genericco
```

Getting below error:-

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module uio_pci_genericco not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-177-generic
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting using the previous kernel version, using advanced options for Ubuntu from the grub boot menu(not recovery mode). I'm not an expert in kernel updates, so I don't know if you need to recompile modules for the new kernel, or if 4.15.0-177-generic is just a bad kernel update, but many people have found that their drivers don't work with 4.15.0-177-generic in Ubu 18.04.

It's very likely related to this: https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg479347.html